# How I can distibute values over the computational cells?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, uniform-distribution, interpolation, boundary-value-problem

I am an engineering student and I try to solve the fluid equations over the computational cells. I have a mathematical question about my property field:

[Computational fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIyqU.jpg)

We know that the properties can be distributed over the cells using a diffusion equation.
But here, I need to distribute the values from the known cells to the solid ones. The criteria will be the zero gradient distribution over the arrows. Can anyone help me to know the mathematical operation for it? What is the equation?